# Refactoring two very similar classes in two applications and one dll

Tags: c++, c++11, dll

I have created two applications (app1 and app2) that are using one dll. 
Each application has it own configuration which uses protobuf for serialization 
and deseirialization. And both aplications has it own class FileConfig. With fallowing methods.

FileConfig.h for both App1 and App2

```
class FileConfig {
    private:
        Config getDefaultConfig();
        Config getConfigFromMessage(const App1ConfigFile& configFile);
    public:
        Config parseFile(const std::string& filename);
        static UFCApi::Config* getConfig(const std::string& filename) {
            FileConfig fileConfig;
            return fileConfig.parseFile(filename);
        };
};
```

FileConfig.cpp in App1

```
Config FileConfig::parseFile(const std::string& filename) {
    std::fstream file(filename, std::ios::in);

    App1ConfigFile configFile; // App1ConfigFile is protobuf generated class 

    std::stringstream buffer;
    buffer << file.rdbuf();
    auto configFileStr = buffer.str();

    if (google::protobuf::TextFormat::ParseFromString(configFileStr, configFile)) {
        return getConfigFromMessage(configFile);
    }

    return getDefaultConfig();
}
```

FileConfig.cpp in App2

```
Config FileConfig::parseFile(const std::string& filename) {
    std::fstream file(filename, std::ios::in);

    App2ConfigFile configFile; // App2ConfigFile is protobuf generated class 

    std::stringstream buffer;
    buffer << file.rdbuf();
    auto configFileStr = buffer.str();

    if (google::protobuf::TextFormat::ParseFromString(configFileStr, configFile)) {
        return getConfigFromMessage(configFile);
    }

    return getDefaultConfig();
}
```

I wanted to refactor this two classes and create base FileConfig with two derived class App1FileConfig and App2FileConfig.

I have done this with fallowing. 
I have put base class in dll, and derived classes in App1 and App2 (respectively).

dll.h

```
template <typename PersistenceConfigFile>
class FileConfig {
    private:
        virtual Config getDefaultConfig() = 0;
        virtual Config getConfigFromMessage(const PersistenceConfigFile& configFile) = 0;
    public:
        Config parseFile(const std::string& filename);
        static Config getConfig(const std::string& filename);
};
```

dll.cpp

```
template <typename PersistenceConfigFile>
Config FileConfig<PersistenceConfigFile>::parseFile(const std::string& filename) {
    std::fstream file(filename, std::ios::in);

    PersistenceConfigFile configFile;

    std::stringstream buffer;
    buffer << file.rdbuf();
    auto configFileStr = buffer.str();

    if (google::protobuf::TextFormat::ParseFromString(configFileStr, configFile)) {
        return getConfigFromMessage(configFile);
    }

    return getDefaultConfig();
}
```

App1.h in App1

```
class App1Config: public FileConfig<App1ConfigFile> {
    private:
        Config getDefaultConfig() {//some implementation};
        Config getConfigFromMessage(App1ConfigFile configFile); {//some implementation};
    public:
        static Config getConfig(const std::string& filename) {
            App1Config app1Config;
            return app1Config.parseFile(filename)
        };
};
```

App2.h in App2

```
class App1Config: public FileConfig<App2ConfigFile> {
    private:
        Config getDefaultConfig() {//some implementation};
        Config getConfigFromMessage(App1ConfigFile configFile); {//some implementation};
    public:
        static Config getConfig(const std::string& filename){
            App2Config app2Config;
            return app2Config.parseFile(filename)
        };
};
```

Dll build passes, and build of App1 and App2 failed wirh error linker cannot find method parseFile.

```
error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "public: class Config __cdecl FileConfig<class App1ConfigFile>::parseFile(class std::basic_string<char,struct std::char_traits<char>,class std::allocator<char> > const &)" (?parseFile@?$FileConfig@VApp1ConfigFile@@@UFCApi@@QEAAPEAVConfig@2@AEBV?$basic_string@DU?$char_traits@D@std@@V?$allocator@D@2@@std@@@Z) referenced in function "public: static class Config * __cdecl App1Config::getConfig(class std::basic_string<char,struct std::char_traits<char>,class std::allocator<char> > const &)" (?getConfig@App1Config@@SAPEAVConfig@@AEBV?$basic_string@DU?$char_traits@D@std@@V?$allocator@D@2@@std@@@Z)
```

Answer (score 0):

Because `parseFile()` belongs to a templated class it needs to be defined in your header `dll.cpp`.

Answer (score 0):

Templates and DLLs don't play together very well. You'd need to have the implementation in the header, but then there will be actually nothing to load from the DLL.

You could get around that by explicit instantiation in the dll:

```
template class FileConfig<App1ConfigFile>;
template class FileConfig<App2ConfigFile>;
```

But that is just a work-around at best, because if you add another config type you'd need to add the explicit instantiation to the DLL (and rebuild it) as well.

(btw. when speaking about DLL, that appears to be Windows, so your class declaration will need to use `__declspec(dllexport/dllimport)`)

In my opinion the best would be to create a common interface for the file config (which will do the work that can't be done by the `FileConfig` itself via virtual calls) and pass it to the `FileConfig` constructor (or to the parse method) via reference, so that the `FileConfig` would not need to be templated and thus can be provided by the DLL.